# ISO8601 date from server is not visible in the label

Tags: ios, swift4

I am getting a date in response from the server which i want to display in the label but when i am displaying it, nil is returned plz help.

my code:

```
let pulledDate = "2018-04-27T02:05:00+00:00"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZZ"
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: pulledDate!) // nil
```

Comment: Your format doesn't match you input

Comment: what should be the correct format

Comment: I suspect, based on you example input (and testing in playground) `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ` might work

Comment: In iOS 10, you can simple using `let formatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
let date = formatter.date(from: "2018-04-27T02:05:00+00:00")`

Comment: That part ".SSS" doesn't appear in your string. So how do you hope that the `dateFormatter` find the date from that string?

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:

You were passing the Wrong Format I guess

### Way One

```
let pulledDate = "2018-04-27T02:05:00+00:00"
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"
    let date = dateFormatter.date(from: pulledDate)
    print(date!)
```

**The Output**

[image]

---

### Way Two

```
let pulledDate = "2018-04-27T02:05:00+00:00"
    let dateFormatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
    let date = dateFormatter.date(from: pulledDate)
    print(date!)
```

The Output:

[image]

Use it the Way you Want.

Hope this help.